# How to make the background of a Gridview scroll

Tags: android, gridview

I need to design some kind of book-shelf-looking view for an Android app I'm developing. First thing I thought to use was a gridview where each item would be a book in the shelf. I already have the art done and after doing the server side connection I end up with a nice looking book shelf filled with books.

But as soon as I get more books than the screen can fit, the GridView allows me to scroll down to see more books, which is the behaviour that I expect. What I didn't expect was the background image to stay in one place while the gridview containing the books slides up.

So this is a broad question, is there any way to accomplish what I want with a Gridview? Or should I better start looking for other alternatives?

Comment: did u done the implementation..? I Just Drawn shelf lines on the Gridview extended class in onDraw based on Book Image Height . But When i scroll the gridview the items are scrolling. But the Grid not gets scrolling. What i want is, When i Scroll the GridView the items has to scroll with the Shelf Lines... Can u pls help me...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sample application written by an Android engineer includes a class that extends GridView to create a bookshelf that scrolls correctly:
http://code.google.com/p/shelves/

Or more specifically:
http://code.google.com/p/shelves/source/browse/trunk/Shelves/src/org/curiouscreature/android/shelves/view/ShelvesView.java

Comment: I was just about to suggest this - definitely the way to go!

Comment: Thanks Christopher, I'm just taking a look at that code at the moment, seems like the way to go indeed.

Answer (score -4):

Put your GridView inside of [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html)

Comment: I tried that before, and just putting my GridView as a child of a ScrollView didn't solve it. Maybe it needs some more tweaking, I don't know.

Comment: This is a bad idea, you shouldn't put any kind of AbsListView inside a scrollview, as the listview already scrolls. The key is to draw the background at an offset relative to the scroll amount as is done in the Shelves application.